# json-schema-validator not validating all items of an array but only the first one

Tags: json, schema

I have below two schemas :

**A.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":
    {
        "ArgumentChoice":{
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {"$ref" : "B.json"}
        }
    }
}
```

**B.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title" : "ArgumentChoiceType",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "ArgumentInt" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties":{
                "Value":{
                    "type" : "integer"
                }
            }
        },
        "ArgumentString" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties":{
                "Value":{
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the json request that is validated against A.json :

```
{
    "ArgumentChoice" : [
    {
        "ArgumentInt" : {
            "Value" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "ArgumentString" :
        {
            "Name" : "JOB_NAME",
            "Value" : "test"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that when I pass Value of `ArgumentInt` as string, it fails because it accepts integer value and I can see it in the report message.
But when I pass Value of `ArgumentString` as integer it still fails, but I cannot see in the message that it failed due to wrong type entered.
I guess only the first array element in `ArgumentChoice` is getting validated against the schema because it fails if I place `ArgumentString` above `ArgumentInt` with the wrong value type in `ArgumentString`.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I created the combined schema from A.json and B.json to test online.
I am able to get the error message for the 2nd case as well.

Combined Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ArgumentChoice": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "ArgumentInt": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Value": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "ArgumentString": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Value": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Input Used

```
{
    "ArgumentChoice" : [
    {
        "ArgumentInt" : {
            "Value" : "test"
        }
    },
    {
        "ArgumentString" :
        {
            "Name" : "JOB_NAME",
            "Value" : 1
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

[image]
Let me know if you have more questions.